# Error in enable SSL in Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl, https

I want to enable SSL localhost in Ubuntu 18.04 and i went through the steps according to the [this order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946171/10695748) but when i enter `sudo service apache2 restart` show me this error

Error:`Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName 172.20.6.59
    ServerAlias 172.20.6.59
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What's the actual error message in error.log or journalctl?

Comment: @grawity [link](https://throwbin.io/zJMmtdQ)